# Difference in attitudes between the Tanya and Mesilat Yesharim

Tags: mussar-ethics, tanya, mesilas-yesharim

As far as I understand both Sefer Ha'Tanya and Mesilat Yesharim consult the man how to improve his characteristics and to be a better person. They instruct the man step by step. What are the differences between the two approaches? Are they complementary or do they contradict one another?

Comment: I am not a specialist, but it seems that the Tanya addresses the subjective feeling and the lack of mastery of the person and try to help to make sense and deal with it. The mesilat yesharim addresses the purely conscious part of the man and gives a guideline to check yourself. He doesn't address what to do when you are outside

Comment: Yeah, they're topically different. The comparison you are asking for would be very difficult to do.